# Duda sobre eficiencia - JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Tengo el siguiente código que lo que hace es obtener de un JSON los datos de un cargo y los recorre.

Tengo dos formas de hacerlo y no se cual podria ser la mejor o mas eficiente:

**Archivo JSON**

```json
{
    "cargos":{
        "DEVS":[
            ["Dev","RED"],
            [ "Dev j","GREEN"]
        ]
    }
}
```

**Primera forma**

```
//la variable nameCargo = "DEV"
const cargos= ROLES.cargos[nameCargo]
installCargo(cargos)
```

**Funcion installCargo**

```
installCargo(cargos) {
    for(let [cargo,color] of cargos){
        console.log('el Cargo= ',cargo,'el color=',color)
        //aqui hay mas codigo pero es referente a Discord js
    }
}
```

**Segunda forma**

```
const roles = ROLES.cargos[nameCargo].map(cargo=>installCargo(cargo))
```

**Funcion installCargo**

```
installCargo(cargo) {
    console.log(`Se esta instalando el cargo ${cargo}`)
    //codigo de Discord js
}
```

No sé cual de las 2 formas seria la óptima, la primera recibe todo el array de los cargos y lo recorre para ser "instalado" y la segunda recibe cada uno de los cargos y lo "instala"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Aunque la pregunta parece de opinión, es importante recalcar que existen diferentes tipos de optimizaciones para cada función que se utilice en JS.

Las computadoras hoy en día son suficientemente rápidas para que este tipo de optimizaciones sean necesarias solo cuando se requiere exprimir cada milisegundo de la ejecución, que para eso voltearías a un lenguaje como C, C++, Rust etc.

Sin embargo puedes ocupar la sentencia `console.time("etiqueta");`  y `console.timeEnd("etiqueta");` para medir el tiempo que tarda en ejecutarse un fragmento del código.

```js
let array = [];

for (let i = 0; i != 100000; i++) {
    array.push(["Element: " + i, "LOREM"]);
}

let array2 = array.map(x => x);

console.time("forOfLoop");
for (element of array) {
    element.push("newValue")
}
console.timeEnd("forOfLoop");

console.time("forEachFunc");
array2.forEach(element => element.push("newValue"));
console.timeEnd("forEachFunc");
```

esta ejecución dio como resultado

```
forOfLoop: 34.408ms
forEachFunc: 5.004ms
```

así que en este caso particular es mejor la función forEach(). pero te recomendaría que lo hicieras en tu código y tomaras una decisión en base a ello.

Comment: Buena respuesta, `.forEach()` es mejor y, en el caso de OP, no debería usarse `.map()` porque no necesita un nuevo arreglo, solo ejecutar la función para cada elemento.