# Cómo recorrer un JSON

Tags: javascript, json

Tengo el siguiente archivo JSON

El JSON representa unos roles, dentro de los roles hay unas categorias como lo son `MOD` y `ADMINISTRATOR`  y dentro de estas categorias estan los roles que se le asignara a un usuario, estos roles contienen el nombre del rol y un color.
Si alguien tiene una mejor forma de estructurar el JSON puede decirmelo. Gracias

```
{
    "roles":{
        "MOD":[
            ["Mod","ORANGE"],
            ["Staff","GRAY"]
        ],
        "ADMINISTRATOR":[
            ["ADMIN","RED"],
            ["CO-ADMIN","BLUE"],
            ["MANAGER","SKYBLUE"]
        ]
    }
}
```

y lo que Quiero es poder acceder a cada una de los objetos que estan adentro de `roles`, pero no se como hcaer esto
. he intentado esto.

```
const ROLES = require("roles.js")
const roles = ROLES.roles

for(rol of roles){
     console.log(rol)
}
```

pero me dice `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: roles is not iterable` asi que no se me ocurre que podria hacer.

Como dije quiero obtener los arrays de `MOD` y `ADMINISTRATOR` pero quiero hacerlo de forma dinamica es decir obtner todos los array dentro de roles ya que en un futuro puedo agregar mas.

Como un dato extra al obtener los arrays (MOD, ADMINISTRATOR, etc) voy a tener que acceder a los elementos que hay dentro de estos

Comment: Revisa mi respuesta editada, al final, y el último código con un ejemplo de incorporación de un nuevo rol. Cuando diseñas un JSON debes pensarlo como una expresión de tu modelo de datos y en la facilidad para reconocer, leer sus propiedades. Es sólo un ejemplo de cómo podría quedar.

Comment: ok ya la reviso, gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu JSON actual tiene dos elementos iterables (arrays) que son `MOD` y `ADMINISTRATOR` y  se encuentran dentro del objeto JSON `roles`.

Podrías iterarlos accediendo directamente a ellos, por ejemplo:

```js
const rolesOriginal=
`{
    "roles":{
        "MOD":[
            ["Mod","ORANGE"],
            ["Staff","GRAY"]
        ],
        "ADMINISTRATOR":[
            ["ADMIN","RED"],
            ["CO-ADMIN","BLUE"],
            ["MANAGER","SKYBLUE"]
        ]
    }
}`;

const json=JSON.parse(rolesOriginal);

json.roles.MOD.forEach(function(item) {
    console.log(item.join());
});

json.roles.ADMINISTRATOR.forEach(function(item) {
    console.log(item.join());
});
```

---

#### Edición

Una estructura que representaría mejor lo que expresas en la actualización de tu pregunta sería la que sigue.

El JSON que ves en el código se define brevemente como un conjunto de `roles`, **todos ellos** con una categoría (`category`) y con un grupo de usuarios (`users`) los cuales a su vez tienen una propiedad `name` y `color`. Lo más importante de todo esto es que este JSON representaría una lógica en tu aplicación expresada en un modelo de datos. Generalmente ese modelo de datos se acopla y trabaja junto a otras herramientas, a veces en diferentes contextos como bases de datos, APIs, Servicios Web, aplicaciones móviles, páginas web, etc. **El modelo de datos es el mismo** y luego lo expresas o lo extiendes en todas aquellas partes donde lo necesites.

Este JSON por ejemplo es mapeable a una tabla de base de datos, a una clase de tipo entidad o POJO o de cualquier otro tipo en una aplicación más amplia.

Lo fundamental es que respetes las  **reglas definidas en el JSON**, que representarían la forma lógica en que trabaja tu aplicación **en cualquier contexto**, de modo que sea flexible y se pueda leer siempre con el mismo código.

```js
const jsonOriginal =
  `{
   "roles":[
      {
         "category":"MOD",
         "users":[
            {
               "name":"Mod",
               "color":"ORANGE"
            },
            {
               "name":"Staff",
               "color":"GRAY"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "category":"ADMINISTRATOR",
         "users":[
            {
               "name":"ADMIN",
               "color":"RED"
            },
            {
               "name":"CO-ADMIN",
               "color":"BLUE"
            },
            {
               "name":"MANAGER",
               "color":"SKYBLUE"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}`;
const json = JSON.parse(jsonOriginal);

json.roles.forEach(function(rol) {
  console.log('Categoría:',rol.category);
  rol.users.forEach(function(user) {
    for (key in user) {
      console.log(key, ':', user[key]);
    }
  });
});
```

Imaginemos que se agrega otro rol, el JSON será modificado, pero NO el código que hemos usado para leerlo:

```js
const jsonOriginal =
  `{
   "roles":[
      {
         "category":"MOD",
         "users":[
            {
               "name":"Mod",
               "color":"ORANGE"
            },
            {
               "name":"Staff",
               "color":"GRAY"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "category":"ADMINISTRATOR",
         "users":[
            {
               "name":"ADMIN",
               "color":"RED"
            },
            {
               "name":"CO-ADMIN",
               "color":"BLUE"
            },
            {
               "name":"MANAGER",
               "color":"SKYBLUE"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "category":"EDITOR",
         "users":[
            {
               "name":"Edit",
               "color":"WITHE"
            },
            {
               "name":"Print",
               "color":"BLACK"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}`;
const json = JSON.parse(jsonOriginal);

json.roles.forEach(function(rol) {
  console.log('Categoría:',rol.category);
  rol.users.forEach(function(user) {
    for (key in user) {
      console.log(key, ':', user[key]);
    }
  });
});
```

**Acceder a elementos específicos dentro de un array**

Si quieres acceder a elementos específicos dentro de un array puedes usar el índice, teniendo en cuenta que los arrays se indexan a partir de cero, por lo que el primer elemento estaría en el índice `0`, el segundo elemento en el índice `1` y así sucesivamente.

Puedes crear referencias a los elementos:

```
let firstRol=json.roles[0];      //1er objeto dentro de roles
let firstUser=firstRol.users[0]; //1er objeto dentro de users del 1er rol
```

O acceder directamente, navegando según la estructura del json e indicando los índices. Por ejemplo:

```
let firstItem =json.roles[0].users[0];       //1er user en el 1er rol
let secondItem=json.roles[0].users[1];       //2do user en el 1er rol

let secondRolItem3=json.roles[1].users[2];   //3er user en el 2do rol
```

Veamos un ejemplo funcional:

```js
const jsonOriginal =
  `{
   "roles":[
      {
         "category":"MOD",
         "users":[
            {
               "name":"Mod",
               "color":"ORANGE"
            },
            {
               "name":"Staff",
               "color":"GRAY"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "category":"ADMINISTRATOR",
         "users":[
            {
               "name":"ADMIN",
               "color":"RED"
            },
            {
               "name":"CO-ADMIN",
               "color":"BLUE"
            },
            {
               "name":"MANAGER",
               "color":"SKYBLUE"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}`;
const json = JSON.parse(jsonOriginal);

/*
  Los arrays se indexan a partir de 0
  por tanto aquí roles[0] sería el 1er objeto dentro de roles
*/
let firstRol=json.roles[0];
/*
  Y aquí users[0] sería el primer objeto dentro de users
*/
let firstUser=firstRol.users[0];
console.log('Prueba primer rol:');
console.log(firstUser.name,firstUser.color);

/*
  Se puede acceder también directamente de este modo...
  Probemos con el 2º rol, que está en el índice 1,
  y su 3er usuario que está en el índice 2
*/
let secondItem=json.roles[1].users[2];
console.log('Prueba segundo rol:');
console.log(secondItem.name,secondItem.color);

/*
json.roles.forEach(function(rol) {
  console.log('Categoría:',rol.category);
  rol.users.forEach(function(user) {
    for (key in user) {
      console.log(key, ':', user[key]);
    }
  });
});
*/
```

Comment: Gracias, pero lo que queria era hacerlo "dinamicamente" ya que en un futuro puedo agregar mas elementos y entonces mi tendria que hacer esto para cada uno. En resumen quiero obtener cada uno de esos arreglos y posteriormente iterar en cada elemento de este

Comment: @christian te entiendo, pero esa estructura no te ayuda realmente a tener datos dinámicos. Puede que no estés organizando tu JSON de la mejor manera. Si nos dices qué entidad o contexto intentas representar en el JSON quizá se te podría sugerir una mejor estructura. O, da un ejemplo de un nuevo contenido hipotético.

Comment: @A .Cedano listo lo agrege en la pregunta

Comment: Cómo podria acceder a un elemento en especifico de cada categoria?por ejemplo acceder al primer elento de `users` de la categoria `mod` y extraer el `name` y el `color`?, algo como en esta [Pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/446097/183782)

Comment: @christian revisa la respuesta editada, al final agregué una sección al respecto.

Answer (score 1):

Según veo en tus comentarios buscas dinámicamente entrar a cada objeto de **roles** e imprimir el contedido de su array. No se si es lo más elegante pero es lo que se me ocurre:

```js
const ROLES = {
    "roles":{
        "MOD":[
            ["Mod","ORANGE"],
            ["Staff","GRAY"]
        ],
        "ADMINISTRATOR":[
            ["ADMIN","RED"],
            ["CO-ADMIN","BLUE"],
            ["MANAGER","SKYBLUE"]
        ]
    }
}

const roles = ROLES.roles
for(rol in roles){
  console.log('objetos del array del rol:', rol)
  for(let r of roles[rol]){
    console.log(r)
  }
}
```

Comment: Gracias eso fue lo que hice, hubiera aceptado tu respuesta pero la eliminaste, @A.Cedano me dio una mejor forma de organizar la estructura y a la vez responde mi pregunta por eso la acepte, de lo contrario me hubiera quedado con la tuya :b

Answer (score 0):

Debes recordar que cuando recorres un array no puedes obtener un valor utilizando la nomenclatura del punto para resolver un valor, solamente lo puedes hacer con objetos, es por eso que en el ciclo for que tienes te da el error `TypeError: roles is not iterable` por que no es un array como tal y no lo puede iterar, lo que deberías hacer es algo como esto:

```
const ROLES = require("roles.js")
const roles = ROLES.roles

for(rol of roles.MOD[0]){
     console.log(rol)
     //["Mod","ORANGE"]
     //["Staff","GRAY"]
}

for(rol of roles.ADMINISTRATOR[0]){
     console.log(rol)
     //["ADMIN","RED"]
     //["CO-ADMIN","BLUE"]
     //["MANAGER","SKYBLUE"]
}
```

recuerda que en tu json, el campo `MOD` y el campo `ADMINISTRATOR` son arrays, y es eso mismo lo que se debe iterar, para poder resolver un item de esos array podrias simplemente   llamar al valor utilizando `[0]` para el primer item y asi sucesivamente.

```
const ROLES = require("roles.js")
const roles = ROLES.roles

for(rol of roles.MOD[0]){
     console.log(rol[0])
     //"Mod"
     //"Staff"
}

for(rol of roles.ADMINISTRATOR[0]){
     console.log(rol[0])
     //"ADMIN"
     //"CO-ADMIN"
     //"MANAGER"
}
```

Comment: Gracias, pero de igual forma como le comente a @A.Cedano quiero obtener los array de MOD y ADMINISTRATOR ya que en un futuro puedo agregar mas y quiero hacerlo de forma dinamica

Comment: deberías contextualizar tu pregunta para poder recibir una respuesta mas concreta